# how to manage strict policy warning while accessing database

Tags: android, multithreading

when i try to insert some values in database , i am getting following warning

```
android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=2079 violation=2
```

after exploring on this i came to know that

> StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network
>   access on the application's main thread, where UI operations are
>   received and animations take place. Keeping disk and network
>   operations off the main thread makes for much smoother

so now am using a `Thread` and i am performing database insertion and deletion in that too as follows

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


                //insert data into database



            }
          }).start();
```

*but the issue is everytime somewhere or the other place i can't create thread to perform small small operations.
so is there any uniform or a common way to perform such database task ?
moreover do i need to keep track of this anonymous threads which i am creating  ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the issue is everytime somewhere or the other place i can't create thread to perform small small operations

Disk I/O and network I/O are not "small small operations" from the standpoint of the main application thread.

> so is there any uniform or a common way to perform such database task ?

Perform your database operations using a `Thread`, `AsyncTask`, `IntentService`, etc., depending upon your needs.

> moreover do i need to keep track of this anonymous threads which i am creating ?

That depends upon the nature of the threads.

Taking your code snippet, if `//insert data into database` does just that, while it will take too long to perform on the main application thread, it still should be done in milliseconds or seconds. At that point, the thread will terminate on its own. So long as you are not doing anything that might cause the thread to run indefinitely, you probably do not need to worry about the thread itself.

Another approach would be to have a single thread that runs constantly, blocking on a work queue. This could be a `HandlerThread`, or it could be a regular `Thread` using something like a `LinkedBlockingQueue`. Then, when the rest of your app wants to perform some I/O, it posts a message to that work queue, causing the thread to go do that work. In this case, you *do* need to make sure that you get rid of this thread when you are done with it, because it is designed to run forever, waiting for more work. Unfortunately, it may be difficult to determine when you are indeed done with it. That's one reason why it is often times simpler to just spawn a short-lived disposable thread for a single transaction (e.g., set of database inserts).

Comment: i am not aware about the `LinkedBlockingQueue` with `HandlerThread` so is it fine to use it `Handler` and send data using `SendMessage` whenever i want to perform insertion or deletion of database ?

Comment: @Hunt: The default `Handler` is tied to the main application thread, so messages sent to it are handled on the main application thread, which is not what you want. A `HandlerThread` is a separate thread with an attached `Handler`, and *that* `Handler` would process its messages on that separate thread.

Comment: you have any example of it ? `LinkedBlockingQueue` or `HandlerThread`

Comment: @Hunt: No, sorry, because I don't use those techniques.

Comment: so how you handle these strict policy warning while accessing database?

Comment: @Hunt: I perform my database operations using a `Thread`, `AsyncTask`, `IntentService`, etc., depending upon my needs. IOW, the code in your question is in line with what I would do.

Comment: ok i am using thread , so can you give me some example of `AsyncTask` and `IntentService` with database ?

Comment: @Hunt: I don't have an `IntentService` database sample handy, but here is one using `AsyncTask`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/Constants

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare's answer is correct. Another solution is `ASyncQueryHandler` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html

You can call , `startInsert` to do your insert Asynchronously, and override `onInsertComplete` if you want to be notified when it completes.

A 'simple' example is here [ExpandableList2](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/85f9f764507761e011fc14398e7ddf08b5d383c5/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.java)

Comment: Note that this is only for queries, much like using `CursorLoader` with a `ContentProvider`. These reduce the number of threads that you fork yourself, though threads are still forked under the covers.